# Django 1.11 dict as input to .create?

Tags: django, dictionary, serialization

Django 1.11

I have working code

```
something = MyModel.objects.create(
a=1,b=2
)
```

where a and b are the fields.

I would like to change it to:

```
mydict = {'a' : 1, 'b' : 2}
something = MyModel.objects.create(mydict)
```

I tried

```
something = MyModel.objects.create(**mydict)
```

and

```
something = MyModel(**mydict)
```

Both give this error:

> Exception Value:   'str' object has no attribute '__name__'

I realise I can write some code to do it item by item, just curious if there is a direct way to do that, seems to be something useful..
Thanks!

Comment: can you add your model definition please?

Comment: It looks more to me like one of the parameters isn't set property and is given a string where it's expecting a foreign key model type, can you add more context and be a bit more explicit in what your code does? You can obfuscate if you want just don't change types.

Comment: Thank you all.  All of the values in the dict are foreign keys. The problem was caused by the data, now it's corrected and working. One of the keys was spelled incorrectly, and one of the foreign keys had an invalid value due to changed default value. Unfortunately I can not tell which one of the two caused that since the database with all the data was replaced. I tried to misspell that key again but that now just caused .create to fail silently instead of giving me that "\__name__" error.

Answer (score 0):

you can try the following:
`something = MyModel(**mydict)`

And don't forget to save:
`something.save()`

Comment: something = MyModel(**mydict) gives the error that made me to ask this question :-:)

Comment: The important point is the save().
Can you provide a little bit more detail about your dictionary?
Because this solution is supposed to work. So maybe their is a problem elsewhere.

Comment: I put a comment about the resolution under the question, somewhat still nebulous maybe because things evolved. As of ".save()", prior to the fix I was not even getting to .save() call since .create call was  catching an exception.